# I am trying to scroll but scrolling is not performing correctly

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

If I am trying to scroll, it's doesn’t scroll correctly. It only scrolls a little bit and it's difficult to scroll it upwards again.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
        children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 10),
                child: Text(
                    "اطلب حسب الفئة",
                )
            ),
            Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
                child: GridView.count(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 3,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    children: [
                        ...(categoryItems)
                        .map((catItem) => Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

Comment: Tanay check comments and updated ans

Comment: did you try what I suggested in comments

Comment: Use `listview` instead of `column`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `SingleChildScrollView` inside `Expanded` as below.

```dart
Expanded(
    child : SingleChildScrollView(...)
)
```

NOTE : You should use `Expanded` only within a `column`, `row` or `flex`.

Comment: Hi tanay ,You should use `Expanded` only within a column, row or flex.

Comment: Wrap it within any of the above mentioned widget

Comment: Try replacing your outer Column with a ListView. You may need to put shrinkWrap: true on it.